# Configuring circleci for project structure

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this as my project structure:

```
<parent>
├── <project1>
│   ├── processors
│   │   └── some_processor1.py
├── <project2
│   └── processors
│       └── some_processor2.py
├── <mutual_dependency3>
│   ├── <some_file>
└── tests
    ├── <project1>
    │   └── processors
    │       └── test_thing.py
    ├── <project2>
    ...
```

The problems are as follows:

- Both project 1 and project 2 run on docker where the dockerfile moves the mutual_dependency inside the project1 and project2 during the docker build and not outside of it like displayed. The import statements in each project assume that the mutual_dependency is inside the project1 or project2 folder. I need to do the same for circle in order for the tests to run.
- The tests assume that the working directory is parent/. Can this be set?

So what I need to do:

- set working directoring to `parent/`
- move the mutual dependency into both project folders during test runs.

Given these 2 issues, how do I setup a `circle.yml` file?